# Get file's owner and group using boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem, fstat

I want to get the owner and group from a file using boost::filesystem, but never found any way to do so.

I can get the file's permissions, but as I don't know the file's owner this just doesn't mean anything.

I found the posix fstat function, but again I'd like to use boost or another C++ library rather than C functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the owner of a file or directory using boost filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681929/how-can-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-using-boost-filesystem)

Comment: @CharlesB How can my post duplicate this? The other may be a duplicate but not mine as its the older one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're asking to do is a Unix system call.  But you don't want to call it?  Why?  What possible value could boost provide?  It's not portability, as nothing outside of a Unix is going to have a meaningful st_gid field.

Comment: It will be portable to all posix systems :) So perhaps there are so C++ library implementing this. And as I'm working on a CLI tool, it's not really designed for Windows and other non-posix systems

Comment: POSIX is spec, Unix is an implementation, it's not exactly the same. A posix system may not be a unix system. And in that case you NEVER use any library, cause everything is a system call. Why should I use `new` as it's resolved to a syscall? It's the same here.

Comment: Do you want your answer or not?  Clearly everything is not a system call: you cannot open a window, uncompress a zlib stream or compute a MD5 hash with a system call.  But you **can** stat a file.  You are writing in a language which provides unobstructed access to your platform's syscalls.  Use it.

Comment: Just one point, a syscall involves an interruption instruction which cannot be reproduced natively in C or C++. The fstat functions is already a wrapper around a syscall, not a syscall itself, so there may be C++ lib which does the same. You present me the syscall as THE solution when it's just one wrapper. But if there is no C++ solution just say it, that's all I want to know!

Comment: You have to **execute** the system in all cases.  That is how, fundamentally, your process asks the OS for the information.  All wrappers ultimately end up making a trap to the OS.  The stat/fstat functions in the C library are the simplest possible wrappers, and as they are natively available to you in C/C++, they are what you should use.

Comment: The fact they are the simplest doesn't mean you should use them, or why are other libraries for? If I have to do some networking I'll use some OO library to make things easier, I won't issue directly the syscall used to redirect data to a specific memory area in the same time as a signal is send to the network controller.
But anyway, as I've not any other answer I'll still use the C function, and thanks for the discussion :)

Comment: @AndyRoss `boost::filesystem` does provide an abstraction for POSIX permission bitmasks like read/write/execute, so it absolutely makes sense to ask why `boost::filesystem` omits an abstraction for POSIX owner/group.